# Vacuum balloon / airship with balloons as shell segments

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, vacuum, buoyancy, lift

What are the problems with the following idea for building a vacuum balloon / airship? The question is targeted at the "making it float" part, ignoring other problems with super-light airships (steering, weather, etc).

Build the shell of the vacuum chamber out of smaller gas-filled balloons, like this:

[image]

The blue parts are gas-filled chambers, either using air, or for an extra lift, helium. The red part is vacuum. It is drawn as a circle, but I'm obviously thinking of a sphere.

The blue chambers would obviously not stay concave on their inwards-facing surface. That is just my poor drawing skills.

The material needed for the blue chambers would have to withstand the gas pressure vs. vacuum. A cheap toy balloon won't, but as far as a quick internet search goes, making a shell that can hold e.g. 1 atm of air vs. vacuum is certainly possible.

Fixing the individual segments is probably the interesting part. The "wedge" shape is intended to make them lock against each other from the air pressing them together, but being non-rigid, that alone will not be sufficient. The segments are glued together to fix that problem.

Comment: Why do you need the blue parts? Wouldn't it be more effective just having the vacuum part?

Comment: you cannot do this without compressive stress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in your proposal, the balloons themselves provide only tensile strength. The resistance to compression comes from the pressure of the air inside the chambers. Let $R$ be the inside radius of the balloon shell, and let $a$ be the thickness of the shell. (So the outside radius is $R+a$.)

Now consider what happens when the radius shrinks to $R-dR$. The outside radius shrinks to $R+a-dR$, meaning that the device now displaces $4\pi(R+a)^2dR$ less air. This is energetically favourable, leading to a reduction of energy of $4\pi(R+a)^2dR \cdot 1$atm. On the other hand, the air inside the chambers now occupies $4\pi((R+a)^2-R^2)dR$ less volume, which is energetically unfavourable. If $P$ is the pressure inside the chambers, then the energy increases by $4\pi((R+a)^2-R^2)dR \cdot P$. Thus, the overall change in energy is:

$$
\Delta E = 4\pi dR \left( P((R+a)^2-R^2) - 1\text{atm}(R+a)^2 \right)
$$

If $\Delta E < 0$, the device will be crushed down to a smaller size by atmospheric pressure. Thus, in order to have the device be stable, the following inequality must be satisfied.

$$
\Delta E = 4\pi dR \left( P((R+a)^2-R^2) - 1\text{atm}(R+a)^2 \right) \geq 0
$$

Therefore:

$$
P \geq 1\text{atm} \frac{(R+a)^2}{(R+a)^2-R^2}
$$

Now let's compute the mass of this thing. Suppose that the density of air at atmospheric pressure is $\rho$. The total mass of air displaced by your balloon will be:

$$
\frac{4\pi}{3}\rho(R+a)^3
$$

On the other hand, the mass of the balloon, ignoring the mass of the balloon fabric, will be:

$$
\rho \frac{P}{1\text{atm}} \frac{4\pi}{3} ((R+a)^3-R^3)
$$

(Since density is proportional to pressure.) This is equal to:

$$
\frac{4\pi}{3} \rho ((R+a)^3-R^3) \frac{(R+a)^2}{(R+a)^2-R^2}
$$

$$
=\frac{4\pi}{3} \rho (R+a)^3 \frac{(R+a)^3-R^3}{(R+a)^3} \frac{(R+a)^2}{(R+a)^2-R^2}
$$

$$
=\frac{4\pi}{3} \rho (R+a)^3 \frac{(R+a)^3-R^3}{(R+a)^3-R^2(R+a)}
$$

Since $R$ and $a$ are both positive, we have:

$$
\frac{(R+a)^3-R^3}{(R+a)^3-R^2(R+a)} > 1
$$

Thus, the balloon must be more massive than the air that it displaces. Preventing atmospheric pressure from simply crushing the balloon requires a very high $P$, which means that the air in the shell has a high density. This high density adds enough mass to prevent the balloon from feeling any lift.

If you use helium instead of ordinary air, then you can use a smaller value for $\rho$ in the equation for the mass of the balloon, so you might get lift. However it is clear from the equations that you are best off making $R=0$. i.e. creating an ordinary helium balloon with no vacuum inside.

Answer (score 0):

This structure was proposed and analyzed in https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0610222 (although for a cylindrical geometry). The author's conclusion: "pressurizing with air can never lead to a structure that is lighter-than-air". I analyzed a similar structure for a spherical geometry and came to the same conclusion.

Together with my co-author, I proposed a viable design of a vacuum balloon using currently available materials (https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.05171 and references there).

Comment: What would happen if you used a multi-layered approach where the innermost chamber is a vacuum, the next layer is 1/n atm, the next 2/n atm, ... and the last is (n-1)/n atm, where one layer of the structure would be able to support a difference of 1/n atm. Given today's 3D printing technology, though it might be difficult to evacuate the spacer layers of support material (a non-closed cell separation layer would have to be used), one could conceivably make this material very strong and lightweight and might be more technically feasible than the design you gave, given a large enough printer.

Comment: @Adrian : I have not analyzed such a design, but I am highly skeptical about it, as it seems the layers would have to be very lightweight. Again, I cannot be positive about that.

Comment: Of course, the number of layers would have to be minimised.  Currently, SLM can do layers around 20 micrometers and have been used in creating rocket engines and other items used in aerospace.

Comment: @Adrian : So I don't quite understand two things. Why this approach is more technically feasible than that of our preprint and why the 3D printing technology cannot be applied to the design of our preprint (please note that we refer to a 3D printing technology in the preprint).

Comment: Sorry, where did you refer to 3D printing in that paper?  I did a search on it just now and didn't find the word *3D* or *print* in it anywhere.  What is the "preprint" document that you are referring to? You cannot use 3D printing as it it stands now because you would require supports to keep the voids in the honeycomb.  After the print is complete, how do you expect to remove the support material?  They are closed cell, meaning that the support material has nowhere to go.

Comment: As for more technically feasible, I was only speculating that trying to apply a honeycomb structure between two thn surfaces that would be the skin of a sphere would be unbelievably difficult.  I could be wrong, but by having a pressure gradient between several skins, the skins could be thinner but more prevalent than your design, and not having closed cells would allow removal of the support structure.

Comment: One other thing, wouldn't the voids in the honeycomb be at 1 atm?  If so, then wouldn't the void produce a 1 atm force to the vacuum chamber? Or are you thinking that they would be at maybe 1/2 atm, which would be something like the pressure gradient that I am referring to?  I didn't see that in the document either.  Or maybe the force for the minimal area of one cell would be capable of handling the bridging area?

Comment: @Adrian : "What is the "preprint" document that you are referring to?" https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.05171 "where did you refer to 3D printing in that paper?" Please see ref. 22, although it is only related to manufacturing of the face sheets. However, we mention (but we do not discuss) "architected cellular materials".

Comment: @Adrian : "You cannot use 3D printing as it it stands now because you would require supports to keep the voids in the honeycomb. After the print is complete, how do you expect to remove the support material? They are closed cell, meaning that the support material has nowhere to go." I don't understand that. If you grow your honeycomb structure by gradually increasing the wall height, what seems to be the problem? The substrate can be removed (say, etched), and then you can glue the resulting honeycomb to the face sheets.

Comment: @Adrian : "trying to apply a honeycomb structure between two thn surfaces that would be the skin of a sphere would be unbelievably difficult." I don't understand that. Curved sandwich structures are widely used.

Comment: @Adrian : "wouldn't the voids in the honeycomb be at 1 atm?" This is a very good question, but, according to our analysis, it does not really matter what pressure from zero to 1 atm you have in the voids (provided it is the same in all voids).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103769/discussion-between-adrian-and-akhmeteli).